# How can I set my debugging options to "Step into Specific"?

Tags: uwp, async-await, visual-studio-debugging

I was having problems with async methods interfering with each other or my debugging, and asked a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293298/how-can-i-prevent-one-async-method-from-monopolizing-another).

After changing my code as suggested in the answers there, I now get this when I try to step into (F11) from the async void event handler into the async Task method:

[image]

However, I see no such option when I reach the call to the method from the event handler and right-click on that line.

I looked for a way to set it up in the Debugging > Settings, too, but don't see a "Step Over Properties and Operations" checkbox:

[image]

What do I need to do to reach the breakpoint I have set in the async method?

Comment: The code is not enough to help us reproduce your issue. Maybe you should provide a small sample with your issue.

Comment: I didn't want to copy the same code from the referenced question, but I think that it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is actually there:

[image]

You should **uncheck** the option **Step over properties and operators(Managed only)** and then try to debug again.